# Patenting an invention yet in production

Tags: prior-art

Suppose that I sell a service and that I haven't disclosed anything about the method/software that I use to produce the service deliverables. It happens that the service has a good commercial success so after a couple of years I decide to file a patent application to protect said method/software.

Is the fact that the product was being produced and sold since years to be considered prior art?